# How to display section according to user_id based on allowed section in codeigniter

Tags: php

I am confused what to do after this

I have 4 sections whose id's are 1,3,4,5 
now i have two employee section one is for team leads and 2nd is for employees

team leads are allowed to fill the section of assigned employee

the process is going like this 
 user_id - team_leads 
 assigned_for- employee

```
---------------------------------------
user_id | assigned_for|section_id|month
---------------------------------------
5       |10           |4,5       |jan
---------------------------------------
5       |11           |4         |feb
---------------------------------------
5       |9            |3,4,5     |march
---------------------------------------
5       |8            |1,3,4,5   |june
---------------------------------------
```

its not working like this as mentioned above it display 1,3,4,5 all sections to every employee 
 This is my query

```
$user_id= $this->data['user_id'] = $this->_user['user_id'];     
    $q = 'select group_concat(distinct section_id) as allowed_sections from section_permissions where section_id != 0 and  user_id ='.$user_id;
    $row = $this->section_permission_model->q_single($q);
    $allowed = ($row['allowed_sections'])?explode(',',$row['allowed_sections']):array();
```

in view it display like this 
Name     Date           Month    Action
abc     2016-09-22      aug      edit
def     2016-09-22      jan      edit
abc     2016-09-22      mar      edit
under every same all sections are same

please provide solution